# CsvHelper C# datetime format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: csvhelper

I am using `CsvHelper` library to parse CSV data to C# object. So far, I can parse all this class with these 3 columns.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
}
```

But after I added the DateTime property, it breaks. Class after added new column.

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is my configuration

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                HasHeaderRecord = false,                            
            };
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
            {
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvMap>();                            
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
                foreach (var record in records)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(record.Id);
                }
            }

public sealed class CsvMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public CsvMap()
    {
        string format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
        var msMY = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ms-MY");

        Map(m => m.TransactionDate).TypeConverterOption.Format(format)
          .TypeConverterOption.CultureInfo(msMY);
    }
}
```

and this is my data

```
"Invoice0000001","1,000.00","USD","20/02/2019 12:33:16"
"Invoice0000002","300.00","USD","21/02/2019 02:04:59"
```

Note: The date format in the above date is DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your map is only mapping the date and you don't have an index specified, so it's it's going to use the first column (index 0).

If your format is `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` then why are you specifying `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` as the format?

Changing those 2 things will fix your issue.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("\"Invoice0000001\",\"1,000.00\",\"USD\",\"20/02/2019 12:33:16\"\r\n");
    s.Append("\"Invoice0000002\",\"300.00\",\"USD\",\"21/02/2019 02:04:59\"\r\n");
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
    };
    using (var reader = new StringReader(s.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvMap>();
        csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList().Dump();
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CsvMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public CsvMap()
    {
        string format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
        var msMY = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ms-MY");

        Map(m => m.TransactionDate).TypeConverterOption.Format(format)
          .TypeConverterOption.CultureInfo(msMY).Index(3);
    }
}
```

[image]

Also, `Format` is `Format(params string[] formats)` so you can pass multiple in if you have more than 1 format that could appear.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easier solution for this, not sure if it helps, but when reading the file, make sure the CultureInfo is correct, using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`:

```cs
using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(emailAttachment.Content)))
{
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
    {
        records = csvReader.GetRecords<InductionsFile>();
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```